# How accurate Google My Business api returns the Reviews for all locations of an account?

Tags: java, review, google-my-business-api, google-reviews

I want to know if google my business api returns ALL reviews in each call or it might not return some of them if the number of reviews are a lot?
Using this link
(https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list) , my code is based on the code provided here (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews). The account I am listing its reviews has more than 83000 reviews for its all locations and once I execute the code it might return about 81000 reviews and the second time  2 or 3 thousands more and another time 75000 reviews. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: We've observed the same, not much you can do about it apart from retrying requests...

Comment: Is there any way to understand if a review has been deleted or not, since google might not be accurate? because I cannot trust if once I do not find the reviewId in the returned list of GMB, so it is deleted.

Comment: To check if a review still exists, you can always issue a GET request for that individual review.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for locations with many reviews, the only workaround that exists is already close what you are describing: iterate through the reviews multiple times and aggregate all distinct reviews.